# Google Chrome Canary app fails to open

Tags: high-sierra, dock

I have Google Chrome Canary app installed on a MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra. When I click on the app icon in the Dock, it bounces once and then never opens.

Has anyone else run into this or knows how to resolve it?

Comment: Are you talking about Google Chrome Canary build?

Comment: Yes, that is the one!

Comment: Can you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/336301/edit) the question and specify how did you install it? DMG download from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/?platform=mac) or Homebrew?

Answer (score 2):

I think the icon in the doc is not for the Canary app you just downloaded. The icon in the dock should be an alias to Canary. I would drag Canary from your Applications folder to the dock. This will create a new alias for the version of Canary on your machine. Try this new dock version to ensure it works. If so, delete the older icon from the dock.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered why it was not launching.  I had ben using the guest account when encountering this problem.  When I switched over to an admin account, it would launch, ask me if I wanted to open the app which was downloaded from the internet, ask me if I wanted to send google informations, and then it launched in the admin account.  Then when I switched over to the guest account it would launch just fine.  There is something about Canary that requires that you launch it as another user before you can ever launch it as a guest user.  Weird.